# VS14 SaveFile/OpenFileDialog slow down ending an execution (why?)

Tags: c#, .net, dialog, visual-studio-2015, filestream

Working in Visual Studios 2015, .NET 4.5, C# 6.0.

I'm using the built in .NET dialogs, OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog, and then using the results via RichTextBox.SaveFile(string) and RichTextBox.OpenFile(string) methods. In lieu of the MSDN documentation of these methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf5hy2e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it seems as though the methods should be handling all resources involved (file streams used for saving/loading) internally.

Yet, when I call these methods during a debug execution, ending the execution normally takes about 20s+, while ending the same debug exe without invoking those methods takes about 1s.  Are the methods not closing the filestreams, or is there some other reason VS is having a hard time closing these executions?

sample:

```
    private void SaveAs(ChildForm formInQuesiton)
    {
        DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            formInQuesiton.fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            formInQuesiton.richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            formInQuesiton.Text = MeaningfulText(formInQuesiton.fileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your MeaningfulText method opening the file stream and not closing and disposing of it properly?

Comment: No, all MeaningfulText does is reduce the full file path name (a String) to just the file name (another String)... I should have omitted it from this snippet as it is superfluous to this problem.